# What compilers currently support Haswell transactional memory?

Tags: compiler-construction, intel, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

Which compilers (as of May 2014) are able to generate code that uses the transactional memory capabilities (Restricted Transactional Memory, not simply lock elision)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC, as of [version 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) supports Intel RTM:

> Support for the Intel RTM and HLE intrinsics, built-in functions and code generation is available via -mrtm and -mhle.

It's probably safe to assume that similar intrinsics are available for a recent version of Intel's ICC, however I can't find a particular version that specifies support ([this paper did experimentation with RTM](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rajwar/papers/SC13_TSX.pdf)) .

In addition, support likely exists for various smaller languages and JITs, with more transparent support arriving [sometime in the future.](http://www.mikeperham.com/2013/12/31/rubys-gil-and-transactional-memory/)

Comment: Can you mention the paper name or add another link for it? as the provided link is not working.

Comment: The title is "Performance Evaluation of Intel Transactional Synchronization Extensions for High-Performance Computing". I'll update the link to a working PDF.